# Using CiviGrant as the applicant/recipient

Tags: wordpress, evaluating-civicrm, civigrant

Our charity doesn't offer grants but applies for a fair few. Having had a play around with CiviGrant, I can't see any immediate problem with using the component as a way of tracking grants that we've applied for and received etc. but the documentation from Civi suggests it's only for managing grants going out of the charity:

> In contrast to CiviContribute, which tracks money going *into* your organisation, CiviGrant tracks money going *out* of your organisation. CiviGrant has a data structure and workflows that support the grant application process with the ability to manage the amount applied for, amount received and any reports necessary for the process.

I created a sample organisation as a contact to attach to the grant and all seems OK to use as a way of managing incoming grants. Just wondering if the community knows something I don't as to why this might not work e.g scaling, reports etc.

Comment: Joxley - is there a specific reason that you wouldn't want to use CiviContribute to track grant income to your organisation? Also a small mention for https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.prospect might be useful for opportunity tracking of grants. best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's totally possible - I have one medium size org that uses Grants exclusively for this purpose. We're using some simple Word Replacements -> in civicrm/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1 to help Staff use native CiviCRM Grants to track income:

[image]